# How to call correct mysql data in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to access a mysql database and pull out all lines of code that have a certain value (i.e. an email).

I am using `$result=mysql_query($query);` and then `$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);` to get the results and store them in an array.

I know that from there I can access the data with $row['email'] if it's only one line...but if there are multiple lines in the array, how do I access those?  For example, can I do:

```
$var1 = $row['email'][0];
$var2 = $row['email'][1];
```

etc.?  Is this the right syntax?  If I wanted to put this value back into Mysql, could I `UPDATE ...where email = '$row['email'][1]'";` or do I need it to be a simple variable like `$var1`?

Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend using `MySQLi` instead of `mysql_*` commands. `mysql_*` is deprecated (which means it will not work with future versions of PHP), and as you do things a little differently with `MySQLi`, your question could change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array()` gets the next row each time you call it to get the rest of them you have to loop through them like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $var1 = $row['email'];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc`

```
foreach($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $var = $row['email']
}
```

Don't forget to free your resultset

```
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: It's rarely necessary to free your results, they'll be freed automatically when the script completes.